# How do I include a pre-built shared-object libraries in a python wheel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-wheel

I'm trying to hack together a redistributable python 2.7 wheel that contains some `.so` libs that have already been built for my platform (ubuntu 16.04).  I know the better practice would be to modify `setup.py` to manage the compilation for these packages, but I don't think that's feasible in my case, as the current compilation is using a convoluted `./configure` replacement that generates an enormous `Makefile`.

It seems like I should just be able to put my libraries in a wheel, but I can't find any clear documentation on doing this.  Note that these are hand-build C-extensions, they don't use Cython or anything and there is no actual python source to see once the package is done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include external library with python wheel package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916186/how-to-include-external-library-with-python-wheel-package)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316177/distribute-a-python-package-with-a-compiled-dynamic-shared-library