# Include 3rd party shared libraries along with my shared library in wheel?

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, python-wheel

I've succeeded in building `python3 setup.py build_ext` my C++ python extension shared library.

However; when I do `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` I would like to include other 3rd party `*.so` libraries in the wheel as well.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include external library with python wheel package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916186/how-to-include-external-library-with-python-wheel-package)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316177/distribute-a-python-package-with-a-compiled-dynamic-shared-library